# StreamWrite (Interact) to another Application running within a C# Console App

Tags: c#, bash, cmd, console-application

I am writing a shell in C# using a Console App. Using my Shell I would execute other applications such as ping.exe, takeown.exe etc just like you would with cmd or bash.

I have no problem in redirecting Standard Out from the other process to my Console App. The issue is that **I don't know how to redirect StardardIn properly so that I can interact with the running application**. I.e say I need to enter "y" to confirm an action using cacls.exe.

Here is my code for StandardOut:

**How can I write back to the App?**

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
        (s, e) =>
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
             }
        );
process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); });

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: `process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Y");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write back the data to the app by using `process.StandardInput.WriteLine(message)`
and message should be a string.

You can use `Write()` or `WriteLine()`